# How do I convert text in an EditText component to an integer?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am currently making a simple random number generator in Android Studio as it is my first time coding in kotlin, you put in 2 numbers, and it will pick a random number between said numbers.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rollButton)
        val resultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultsTextView)
        val RandNum1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.RandNum1)
        val RandNum2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.RandNum2)

        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            val rand = java.util.Random().nextInt(RandNum1)
            resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

So currently I have the rollButton which is set to generate a random number when pressed. I also have the resultsTextView to display the chosen number. And I also have RandNum1 and RandNum2 (the user's number choice), I need to find a way to convert the text that I receive from RandNum1/2 into an integer so that I can use it for the random number generator.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the String to an Integer you can use the extension function "toInt()"
like:

```
try{
   val value = RandNum1.text.toString().toInt()
}catch(Exception e){
   // Do something to handle the error
}
```

Comment: You can also use `toIntOrNull()` if you don't care about the exception contents.